# Format Array of Objects into a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash

I have an array of objects and I would like to get it into a format used by react-csv (2D array). The 2D should look like a nested loop, something like

[image: Image of data in spreadsheet program]

and the end result should be like

```
[
  ["Name", "Message", "Column", "configDataType","dbDataType"],
  ["STAGE", "Columns present in source config but not in the database.", "TEST"],
  ["", "", "TEST1"],
  ["", "", "TEST2"],
  ["", "Columns present in database but not in the source config.", ""],
  ["", "Columns with datatype mismatch.", "LAST_NAME", "varchar(50)", "varchar(40)"],
  ["", "", "FIRST_NAME", "varchar(50)", "varchar(40)"],
  ["RAW", "Column sets are identical."],
  ["LAST", "Column sets are identical."],
  ["HIST", "Column sets are identical."],
  ["CORE", "Column sets are identical."],
  ["ADDR", "Column sets are identical."],
  ["CONFIG", "Column sets are identical."],
  ["ACTION", "Column sets are identical."],
]
```

This is what I have done so far, but I am not able to get the intended result. Please advise me on what I am missing.

```js
const data = {
  "STAGE": [{
      "infoLevel": "error",
      "message": "Columns present in source config but not in the database.",
      "columns": [],
      "columnsName": [
        "TEST",
        "TEST1",
        "TEST2"
      ],
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "infoLevel": "error",
      "message": "Columns present in database but not in the source config.",
      "columns": [],
      "columnsName": [],
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "infoLevel": "error",
      "message": "Columns with datatype mismatch.",
      "columns": [{
        "name": "LAST_NAME",
        "configDatatype": "varchar(50)",
        "dbDatatype": "varchar(40)"
      }, {
        "name": "FIRST_NAME",
        "configDatatype": "varchar(50)",
        "dbDatatype": "varchar(40)"
      }],
      "columnsName": [],
      "type": "Table"
    }
  ],
  "RAW": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "LAST": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "HIST": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "CORE": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "ADDR": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "TRAN": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "CONFIG": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "ACTION": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }]
}

const res = _.flattenDeep(Object.keys(data).map(i => {
  return data[i].map(j => {
    return {
      ...j,
      tableName: i
    }
  })
}))

console.log(res.map(i => {
  return [
    i.tableName,
    i.message,
    ...((i.columns.length > 0 ? i.columns : i.columnsName).map(j => typeof j === 'string' ? j : j.name)),
    ..._.compact(((i.columns.length > 0 ? i.columns : i.columnsName).map(j => typeof j === 'string' ? '' : j.configDatatype))),
    ...(((i.columns.length > 0 ? i.columns : i.columnsName).map(j => typeof j === 'string' ? '' : j.dbDatatype)))
  ]
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `TEST1` and `TEST2` are not in the `data`. Instead, `Arun` and `Abnc` are. You may want to amend either your expected result, or your `data`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Amended the data. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use old style imperative code? Try this:

```js
const data = {
  "STAGE": [{
      "infoLevel": "error",
      "message": "Columns present in source config but not in the database.",
      "columns": [],
      "columnsName": [
        "TEST",
        "Arun",
        "Abnc"
      ],
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "infoLevel": "error",
      "message": "Columns present in database but not in the source config.",
      "columns": [],
      "columnsName": [],
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "infoLevel": "error",
      "message": "Columns with datatype mismatch.",
      "columns": [{
        "name": "LAST_NAME",
        "configDatatype": "varchar(50)",
        "dbDatatype": "varchar(40)"
      }, {
        "name": "FIRST_NAME",
        "configDatatype": "varchar(50)",
        "dbDatatype": "varchar(40)"
      }],
      "columnsName": [],
      "type": "Table"
    }
  ],
  "RAW": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "LAST": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "HIST": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "CORE": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "ADDR": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "TRAN": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "CONFIG": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }],
  "ACTION": [{
    "infoLevel": "success",
    "message": "Column sets are identical.",
    "columns": [],
    "columnsName": [],
    "type": "String"
  }]
};

var rows = [];
for (var c1 in data) {
  const list = data[c1];
  for (var i in list) {
    const obj = list[i];
    var c2 = obj.message;
    for (var j in obj.columnsName) {
      rows.push([c1, c2, obj.columnsName[j]]);
      c1 = ""; c2 = "";
    }
    for (var j in obj.columns) {
      const col = obj.columns[j];
      rows.push([c1, c2, col.name, col.configDatatype, col.dbDatatype]);
      c1 = ""; c2 = "";
    }
    if (c2 != "") rows.push([c1, c2]);
    c1 = "";
  }
}

console.log(rows);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get a lot of eslint errors for for..in. Trying to fix those

Comment: You can replace the 3 for...in which use the i and j vars with classic for i=0;i<array.length;i++ while for the outermost loop you can use Object.keys to retrieve the c1 values.